# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right but I'm trying to copy old tables to a new one and I'm having this weird error of invalid lob locator when i don't even have a lob in my program.

**Error:** ERROR in writeRoot1: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275

**Code I added:**

```
   L_cms_exist VARCHAR2(1);

   cursor C_CMS_IMPORT is
      select 'Y'
        from vic_poe_entry pe,
             vic_poe_tb_po_head ptb
       where pe.order_no = ptb.order_no
         and NVL(cms_ind,'N') = 'Y'
         and pe.order_no = L_order_no
         and rownum = 1;
```

**Whole Program:**

```
----WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT sql.sqlcode;
SET ECHO ON;
SET FEEDBACK ON;
SET TERMOUT ON;
SET LINESIZE 32767;
SET TIMING ON;
SET TIME ON;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;
CLEAR BUFFER;

DECLARE
   L_order_no      ORDHEAD.ORDER_NO%TYPE;
   def_struct      VIC_APPROVE_PO_SQL.TAB_COLL;
   col_struct      VIC_APPROVE_PO_SQL.COL_COLL;
   L_error_message RTK_ERRORS.RTK_TEXT%TYPE := NULL;
   L_error_flag    VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
   L_approve_ind   VIC_POE_ENTRY.APPROVE_IND%TYPE;
   L_tb_ind        VIC_POE_ENTRY.TB_IND%TYPE;
   L_update_ind    VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
   L_cms_ind       VIC_POE_ENTRY.CMS_IND%TYPE;
   head_tab        VIC_PROCESS_PREPO_SUBMIT_SQL.head_tab;
   detail_tab      VIC_PROCESS_PREPO_SUBMIT_SQL.detail_tab;

   chk_ctr number:=0;
   L_num_po number:=0;
   L_flag   number:=0;
   L_program_status varchar2(100):=NULL;

   cursor C_num_of_po is
         select value
           from vic_parameter
          where module = 'VICAPPROVEPO'
            and parameter = 'NUM_OF_PO'; 

   cursor C_get_approved_po is
      select order_no,
             tb_ind,
             cms_ind
        from vic_poe_entry
       where status = 'A'
         and processed_date is NULL 
       order by submitted_date asc;

   cursor C_tab_cur is
     select *
       from vic_po_entry_defaults;

   cursor C_col_cur(I_table_name IN vic_po_entry_defaults.TABLE_NAME%TYPE) is
     select *
       from vic_po_entry_defaults
      where table_name = I_table_name;

   cursor C_lock_po is
      select 'x'
        from vic_poe_entry
       where order_no = L_order_no
         for update nowait;

   cursor C_approve_ind is
      select approve_ind
        from vic_poe_entry
       where status = 'A'
         and processed_date is NULL
         and order_no = L_order_no;

   cursor C_tbpo_head is
      select *
        from vic_poe_tb_po_head
       where order_no = L_order_no;

   cursor C_tbpo_detail is
      select x.order_no                    ,
             x.item                        ,
             pi.pack_no                    ,
             x.quote_no                    ,
             x.length                      ,
             x.width                       ,
             x.height                      ,
             x.mstr_pack_sets_unit_per_case,
             x.units_per_set               ,
             x.cubic_feet_manual           ,
             x.cubic_meters_manual         ,
             x.cubic_ft_from_sub_commodity ,
             x.unit_percent                ,
             x.unit_set_first_cost         ,
             x.freight_rate_manual         ,
             x.nested_packname             ,
             x.nested_packcode             ,
             x.selling_royalty             ,
             x.selling_commission          ,
             x.picture_address             ,
             x.load_pct                    ,
             x.mst_packs_unit_case         ,
             x.cubic_ft_calc               ,
             x.unit_calc_elc               ,
             x.ttl_elc                     ,
             x.ext_retail                  ,
             x.first_podtl_budget_month    ,
             x.second_podtl_budget_month   ,
             x.third_podtl_budget_month    ,
             x.fourth_podtl_budget_month   ,
             x.fifth_podtl_budget_month    ,
             x.sixth_podtl_budget_month    ,
             x.dd_ind               ,
             x.last_update_id,
             x.hts,
             x.customs_desc,
             x.item_parent,
             x.misc_cost,
             x.add_val,
             x.cvd_val,
             x.unit_pct_pack,
             x.ttl_first_cost,
             x.ordered_qty

      from
      (
       select tbpo_dtl.order_no                     ,
              rpi.item                              ,
              tbpo_dtl.pack_no                      ,
              tbpo_dtl.quote_no                     ,
              tbpo_dtl.length                       ,
              tbpo_dtl.width                        ,
              tbpo_dtl.height                       ,
              tbpo_dtl.mstr_pack_sets_unit_per_case ,
              tbpo_dtl.units_per_set                ,
              tbpo_dtl.cubic_feet_manual            ,
              tbpo_dtl.cubic_meters_manual          ,
              tbpo_dtl.cubic_ft_from_sub_commodity  ,
              tbpo_dtl.unit_percent                 ,
              tbpo_dtl.unit_set_first_cost          ,
              tbpo_dtl.freight_rate_manual          ,
              tbpo_dtl.nested_packname              ,
              tbpo_dtl.nested_packcode              ,
              tbpo_dtl.selling_royalty              ,
              tbpo_dtl.selling_commission           ,
              tbpo_dtl.picture_address              ,
              tbpo_dtl.load_pct                     ,
              tbpo_dtl.mst_packs_unit_case          ,
              tbpo_dtl.cubic_ft_calc                ,
              tbpo_dtl.unit_calc_elc                ,
              tbpo_dtl.ttl_elc                      ,
              tbpo_dtl.ext_retail                   ,
              tbpo_dtl.first_podtl_budget_month     ,
              tbpo_dtl.second_podtl_budget_month    ,
              tbpo_dtl.third_podtl_budget_month     ,
              tbpo_dtl.fourth_podtl_budget_month    ,
              tbpo_dtl.fifth_podtl_budget_month     ,
              tbpo_dtl.sixth_podtl_budget_month     ,
              tbpo_dtl.dd_ind                       ,
              tbpo_dtl.last_update_id,
              rpi.hts,
              rpi.customs_desc,
              rpi.item_parent,
              rpi.misc_cost,
              rpi.add_val,
              rpi.cvd_val,
              rpi.unit_pct_pack,
              rpi.ordered_qty * tbpo_dtl.unit_set_first_cost AS "TTL_FIRST_COST",
              rpi.ordered_qty
         from vic_poe_items rpi,
              vic_poe_tb_po_detail tbpo_dtl
        where rpi.order_no = L_order_no
          and rpi.order_no = tbpo_dtl.order_no
          and rpi.rec_no = tbpo_dtl.rec_no
          and rpi.pack_ind != 'Y'
        order by tbpo_dtl.order_no,
              tbpo_dtl.pack_no,
              UPPER(decode((SUBSTR(UPPER(tbpo_dtl.nested_packcode),1,1)), 'Z', SUBSTR(UPPER(tbpo_dtl.nested_packcode),2,2), tbpo_dtl.nested_packcode)),
              tbpo_dtl.item) x,
              packitem pi
        where x.item = pi.item(+);
   L_cms_exist VARCHAR2(1);

   cursor C_CMS_IMPORT is
      select 'Y'
        from vic_poe_entry pe,
             vic_poe_tb_po_head ptb
       where pe.order_no = ptb.order_no
         and NVL(cms_ind,'N') = 'Y'
         and pe.order_no = L_order_no
         and rownum = 1;
   RECORD_LOCKED     EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA            EXCEPTION_INIT(RECORD_LOCKED, -54);

BEGIN
   OPEN C_num_of_po;
   FETCH C_num_of_po into L_num_po;
   CLOSE C_num_of_po;


   for tab_rec in C_tab_cur
   LOOP

      col_struct.DELETE;
      ---
      for col_rec in C_col_cur(tab_rec.table_name)
      LOOP
         col_struct(col_rec.column_name) := col_rec.value;
      END LOOP;
      ---
      def_struct(tab_rec.table_name) := col_struct;
   END LOOP;

   SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('OPEN',
                    'C_get_approved_po',
                    'vic_poe_entry',
                    'order_no :'|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
   open C_get_approved_po;
   ---
   WHILE L_flag = 0
   LOOP

      chk_ctr := chk_ctr + 1;

      SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('FETCH',
                       'C_get_approved_po',
                       'vic_poe_entry',
                       'order_no :'|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
      fetch C_get_approved_po into L_order_no, L_tb_ind, L_cms_ind;
      if C_get_approved_po%NOTFOUND then
         exit;
      end if;
      open C_approve_ind;
      fetch C_approve_ind into L_approve_ind;
         ---
         if L_approve_ind = 'N' then
            update vic_poe_entry
               set approve_ind = 'Y'
             where order_no = L_order_no;
            commit;
         end if;
      close C_approve_ind;
      <<force_error_loop>>
      for x in 1..5 LOOP
         BEGIN
            L_error_flag := 'N';      --reset flag
            L_error_message := NULL;  --reset error message
            open C_lock_po;
            close C_lock_po;

            --- Process Item details
            if VIC_POE_PROCESS_ITEM.PROCESS_ITEM(L_error_message,
                                                 L_order_no,
                                                 def_struct) = FALSE then
               ROLLBACK;
               L_error_flag := 'Y';
            end if;
            --- Process PO details
            if L_error_message is NULL
               and L_error_flag = 'N' then
               if VIC_POE_PROCESS_PO.PROCESS_PO(L_error_message,
                                                L_order_no,
                                                def_struct) = FALSE then
                  ROLLBACK;
                  L_error_flag := 'Y';
               else

                  open C_CMS_IMPORT;
                  fetch C_CMS_IMPORT into L_cms_exist;
                  close C_CMS_IMPORT;
                  if nvl(L_tb_ind, 'N') = 'Y' OR L_cms_exist is NOT NULL then
                     SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('OPEN',
                                      'C_TBPO_HEAD',
                                      'VIC_POE_TB_PO_HEAD',
                                      'ORDER_NO: '|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
                     --
                     open C_tbpo_head;
                     --
                     SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('FETCH',
                                      'C_TBPO_HEAD',
                                      'VIC_POE_TB_PO_HEAD',
                                      'ORDER_NO: '|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
                     --
                     fetch C_tbpo_head into head_tab.vic_tbpo_head;
                     --
                     SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('CLOSE',
                                      'C_TBPO_DETAIL',
                                      'VIC_POE_TB_PO_HEAD',
                                      'ORDER_NO: '|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
                     --
                     close C_tbpo_head;
                     --
                     -- Get TB PO Detail Data
                     SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('OPEN',
                                      'C_TBPO_DETAIL',
                                      'VIC_POE_TB_PO_DETAIL',
                                      'ORDER_NO: '|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
                     --
                     open C_tbpo_detail;
                     --
                     SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('FETCH',
                                      'C_TBPO_DETAIL',
                                      'VIC_POE_TB_PO_DETAIL',
                                      'ORDER_NO: '|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
                     --
                     fetch C_tbpo_detail bulk collect into detail_tab;
                     --
                     SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('CLOSE',
                                      'C_TBPO_DETAIL',
                                      'VIC_POE_TB_PO_DETAIL',
                                      'ORDER_NO: '|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
                     --
                     close C_tbpo_detail;
                     --
                     if VIC_PROCESS_PREPO_SUBMIT_SQL.INSERT_UPD_TB_INFO (L_error_message,
                                                                         head_tab,
                                                                         detail_tab,
                                                                         L_update_ind) = FALSE then
                        ROLLBACK;
                        L_error_flag := 'Y';
                     else
                        if VIC_POE_PROCESS_PO.POST_PO_VALIDATION(L_error_message,
                                                                 L_order_no) = FALSE then
                           ROLLBACK;
                           L_error_flag := 'Y';
                        else
                           L_error_flag := 'N';
                           exit force_error_loop;
                        end if;

                     end if;
                  else
                     if VIC_POE_PROCESS_PO.POST_PO_VALIDATION(L_error_message,
                                                              L_order_no) = FALSE then
                        ROLLBACK;
                        L_error_flag := 'Y';
                     else
                        L_error_flag := 'N';
                        exit force_error_loop;
                     end if;

                  end if;
               end if;
            end if;
         EXCEPTION
            when RECORD_LOCKED then
               ROLLBACK;
               L_error_flag := 'L';
         END;

      END LOOP force_error_loop;

      SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('UPDATE',
                       'C_get_approved_po',
                       'vic_poe_entry',
                       'order_no :'|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));

      if L_error_flag = 'N' then
         update vic_poe_entry
            set processed_date = sysdate,
                  is_processed = 'Y'

          where order_no = L_order_no;

      elsif L_error_flag = 'Y' then
         ROLLBACK; --Roll back any changes first.
         ---
         update vic_poe_entry
            set status = 'W',
                float_ind = 'Y'
          where order_no = L_order_no;
          ---

          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error processing order_no: '||L_order_no||' : '||SUBSTR(L_error_message,1,220));
          if LENGTH(L_error_message) > 220 then
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(L_error_message,221));
          end if;
      elsif L_error_flag = 'L' then
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cannot process locked PO : '||L_order_no||'.');

      end if;
      ---
      COMMIT;


      VICAPPS.VIC_SAMPLE.P_UPDATE_SAMPLE_PO_APPROVAL(L_order_no);

      ---
      L_error_flag := 'N';
      L_error_message := NULL;


      if chk_ctr = L_num_po then
         select value
           into L_program_status
           from vic_parameter
          where module = 'VICAPPROVEPO'
            and parameter = 'PROGRAM_STATUS';

         if L_program_status = 'COMPLETED' then
            dbms_output.put_line('PASOK');
            L_flag:= 1;
         end if;

         chk_ctr:= 0;
         L_program_status := NULL; 

      end if;


   END LOOP;
   ---
   SQL_LIB.SET_MARK('CLOSE',
                    'C_get_approved_po',
                    'vic_poe_entry',
                    'order_no :'|| TO_CHAR(L_order_no));
   close C_get_approved_po;
EXCEPTION
   when OTHERS then
      L_error_message := SQL_LIB.CREATE_MSG (' SCRIPT_ERROR ',
                                             SQLERRM,
                                             ' VIC_APPROVE_PO_SQL.SQL ',
                                             TO_CHAR(SQLCODE));
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_error_message);
         ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Comment: 400 lines is too much for me. Please have a look at [mcve]

Comment: @Aleksej Hi, I'm not sure what to remove and might omit necessary information since I was not the one who originally built the code and only added a portion which causes the error. Please see 'Code I added' which is alot smaller. Thanks~

Comment: What is the full error stack? This should also provide the line number where the error appears. Try `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK ||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE );` instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_error_message);`

Comment: Or comment out the exception handler and post the raw error stack. Or run it in the debugger and isolate the line it fails on and the variable values involved.

Comment: "Code I added" is just a flag lookup. Does that reproduce the issue on its own in a new code block? What is the smallest demo you can put together from scratch that reproduces the issue? Otherwise you will need to post `CREATE` statements and sample data for all of the tables etc involved.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Hi, Will try to but takes too long to compile. Will follow up once done. Thanks~
WilliamRobertson Hi, I'll try to re-create one. Thanks~

Comment: From the initial error 'invalid LOB locator specified'.... The first thing I would be checking is what tables have LOB's (BLOB, CLOB).  You do not have any reference to LOBS in the code sample that you provided, this may give you some clues as to where to look in the code.